# Oracle Golden Gate error 00146

Tags: oracle

I am deploying Oracle Golden Gate to sync data from Sql Server 2008 to Sql Server 2008. One of the extract process have stopped.This is the error:

```
2014-12-21 17:22:09  ERROR   OGG-00146  Call to VAMRead returned with error stat
us 600: VAM Client Report <[mssqlvam::CGGSApi::PartialUpdateOperation] Updates a
re not supported on tables that do not have TRANDATA added. TranId: 0000:001b210
9, Table: "dbo"."Sys_MaxKey">.
```

I try to use command:

```
add trandata Sys_MaxKey
```

but the problem still exists,and i can't start `ext002` (extract process name).

Answer (score 1):

The oracle documentation says this about this Golden gate error

> OGG-00146: Call to {0} returned with error status {1,number,0}: {2}
>
> Cause: One of the VAM API functions implemented in the  VAM module
>   returned an error status on completion of the call to that function in
>   the VAM kernel,  after previously reporting a fatal error in the call.
>
> Action: Contact Oracle Support or, if you are working with an  Oracle
>   GoldenGate developer, contact that person

Comment: I have read this document,but can not solve my problem.